# Is there a way to convert a function variable to a string in D?

Tags: function, d, mixins

Is there any way, given a function variable, to get the name of the function as a string? For example, if I have:

```
void function(int) func;
```

Is there some function x() such that I could get:

```
x(func) == "func";
```

? I feel like this would be possible using mixins, but I'm confused as to how to implement this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
func.stringof
```

is what you need.

You could also make a template:

```
template Name(alias Func) { enum Name = Func.stringof; }

void func() { }
pragma(msg, Name!(func));    //prints func()
```

Comment: Please no. stringof is _not_ a reliable feature!

In any case, the original question bugs me. You should never need to know the name of a function symbol; it's a strong code smell. Instead, just specify the known name of whatever template alias you use to access the function in the first place.

Comment: @FeepingCreature: It's not a code smell if you are doing it for reflection, or some sort of human-readable automatic serialisation. I agree that stringof is pretty unreliable though (but this should improve).

Comment: My goal was to make the work of writing D bindings to an existing C library easier. The code so far has TONS of statements like this, one after another:

    if(bindFunction(funcA, "funcA") != BIND_OK) return false;
    if(bindFunction(funcB, "funcB") != BIND_OK) return false;
    ...

I was hoping to eliminate a bunch of boilerplate code.

Comment: On topic, this does do what I had asked in my question, so it's definitely the best answer. However, I think I might have been barking up the wrong tree, and I need a different approach. Thanks Mehrdad!

Comment: @Mark: One note: Be careful about the template version -- `immutable` might have been a better choice than `enum`, because the latter performs an allocation every time the string is used.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution that comes to my mind:

You can have its name stored in a string, and `mixin`'ed where necessary, something like:

```
string func_name = "func";
...
int param = 294;
mixin(func_name ~ "(" ~ to!string(param) ~ ")");
```